# Using sudo /etc/init.d/httpd start complains for log file rights

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, sudo

I created a custom log directory with the root account, and chmoded it to 777 teporarily.

```
ls -la /var/mylogs/log/
total 16
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jun 24 06:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jun 24 06:25 ..
```

When I try to start the service from a user (lets say "myuser", which is in the sudoers files as myuser ALL=(ALL)  ALL), it fails because of the permissions :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd start

Starting httpd: (13)Permission denied: httpd: could not open error log file /var/mylogs/log/httpd_error.log.
Unable to open logs
```

However, the following is successfull :

```
sudo bash
/etc/init.d/http start
```

So I guess these two methods are not equivalent, although to me doing sudo was the same than logging into the root account and issuing the commands.

Any clue ?

Thank you !

Comment: And what OS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 (Tikanga)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system on which the apache2 server is a RedHat 5.6, hence SELinux is activated by default.

The origin of the issue here is that SELinux adds additionnal file permissions on top of the OS ones (ie chmod, chown), see :

```
man httpd_selinux
```

The manual says that explicit context must be set to file/directories so that httpd is allowed to acess them.

Hence, I used the following :

```
chcon -R user_u:object_r:httpd_log_t /var/mylogs/logs
```

You can check the man to get the other permission tokens ( content, scripts..).

Answer (score 2):

The apache2 process should be owner of logging directory instead of root. You can fix this issue by changing owner of log directory (i.e. www-data or group to which apache2 belongs to)

Comment: on redhat this is httpd.

Comment: You are right, this is step 1 ! Although the answer doesn't make it ;) I'll post why in a few secs.